# c# How to set check state of items in a checked listbox if it matches an item in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Here's what I've been trying to do:

If i add members to listbox1, a variable will store those items and turn them into a single string using *stringbuilder*, in which the string will appear as an item on listbox2. I got this working already.

I want to display the selected item on listbox2 to listbox1 as separated string/item which I already got working, but I also want to check all the items on my checklistbox1 that matches the items on listbox1, in which I'm having trouble with since only 1 item is checked on checklistbox1 using for loop.

Hope someone can help me on this one..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ADDPAGE2
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string s;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            //code for adding authors to the listbox
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    string str = (string)checkedListBox1.Items[i];
                    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                }
            }


            //for making a single string variable from all checked items in checkedlistbox
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (object o in listBox1.Items)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(o.ToString() + ",");
            }
            s = sb.ToString();
            listBox2.Items.Add(s);

        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            s = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string[] tokens = s.Split(',');
            for (int y = 0; y < tokens.Count(); y++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(tokens[y]);

                //loop code for checking matching items between listbox and checkedlistbox
                for (int item = 0; item < listBox1.Items.Count; item++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);//First uncheck the old value!
                        //
                        for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
                        {
                            if (checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString() == listBox1.Items[x].ToString())
                            {
                                //Check only if they match! 
                                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: It is very difficult to determine what your program does and is supposed to do. Use names that clearly map to controls on your forms, indicate that items are manually entered into the `CheckedListBox`, etc. In general, try to post code that can compile and function without any speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, there are a couple of issues:

1. `StringBuilder.AppendLine` embeds `NewLine`s into the items you're splitting  out of the selected item from listbox1 therefore the comparisons will never match.
2. You are unchecking the `CheckedListBox` items too far inside the loop and clearing matches you've already found.

Try this instead:

```
    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        //Uncheck the checkedListBox items only once.
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);
        }
        s = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //Remove all the NewLines added by StringBuilder.AppendLine
        s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
        //Split and ensure no empty elements
        string[] tokens = s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //Loop through tokens
        for (int y = 0; y < tokens.Length; y++)
        {
            //Add token to listBox1
            listBox1.Items.Add(tokens[y]);

            //loop through checkedListBox1.Items for each token
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString() == tokens[y])
                {
                    //Check only if they match! 
                    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed. If u can refer me to some books or any learning source material of how you learned to code in c#, i would appreciate that as well, I might learn some new things that i might missed. Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: There are many programming How-To books out there but for me it's always been about the task first - how do I make the computer do something. Then I work and research on that specific task. Based on the difficulties you were having, I suggest focusing on using the debugger and understanding flow control. Stepping through your code with the debugger would quickly reveal both issues. Once you know what is specifically happening, you can work on correcting it.